# what does this $tok =~ s{\\(.)|([\$\@]|\\$)}{'\\'.($2 || $1)}sge; (perl code) mean?

Tags: perl

What does this mean?

```
$tok =~ s{\\(.)|([\$\@]|\\$)}{'\\'.($2 || $1)}sge;
```

This comes from a [cve study blog](https://devcraft.io/2021/05/04/exiftool-arbitrary-code-execution-cve-2021-22204.html) which written in Perl. I know this is a regular expression, the content in the second `{}` should replace that in the first, but I do NOT get what `'\\'.($2 || $1)`means.

Comment: the whole blog mentioned above is right here ```https://devcraft.io/2021/05/04/exiftool-arbitrary-code-execution-cve-2021-22204.html```

Comment: Those `sge` in the end are "_global modifiers_"  -- they specify and affect various ways how this regex is to operate. The "`e`" one means that stuff in the replacement part (second `{}`) is to be evaluated as code, so as a mini program.  Thus, it's just perl code -- double slash in a string (`'\\'`) concatenated (`.`) with `$2` if true (`||`) or `$1` otherwise. A string composed that way is then used to replace the match from the first `{}`. See [modifiers in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

```
$tok =~ s{\\(.)|([\$\@]|\\$)}{'\\'.($2 || $1)}sge;
```

It is a substitution operator `s///` applied to the string `$tok`, with the modifiers `sge`. The delimiters of the operator has been changed from `/` to `{}`. Lets break that regex down

```
s{
    \\(.)              # (1) match a backslash followed by 1 character, capture
       |               # (2) or
    (                  # (3) start capture parens
        [\$\@]         # (4) either a literal $ or @
            |          # (5) or
        \\$            # (6) backslash at the end of line (including newline)
    )                  # end capture parens
}{                         # replace with
    '\\'.($2 || $1)}       # (7) backslash concatenated with either capture 2 or 1
    sge;                   # (8) s = . matches newline, g = match multiple times, e = eval
```

Judging (at a glance) from the rest of that blog code, this code is not written by someone skilled at Perl. So I will take their comments at face value:

```
# must protect unescaped "$" and "@" symbols, and "\" at end of string
```

The eval (8) is apparently to concatenate a backslash with either capture group 2 (2) or 1 (1), depending on which is "true". Or rather, which one matched the string.

Looking closer at the code, (1) and (6) are very similar. The latter one will trigger only at the end of a line that does not have a newline, whereas the first one will handle all other cases, including end of line *with* a newline (because of `/s` modifier).

(1) will match any escaped character, so `\1`, or `\$` or `\\`  anything with a backslash followed by a character. If we look at the replacement part (7), we see that this capture group is the fallback, which will only trigger if the second capture group fails. The second capture group also only matches if the first fails. Confusing? Maybe a little.

(2) triggers if the matching character is not a backslash followed by a character. Now we are looking for a literal `$` or `@`. Or failing that, a backslash at the end of line. But wait a minute, we already checked for backslash? Yes, but this is an edge case.

In the case of (1) matching, `$2` will be undefined, and `$1`, the first capture group, a single character, will be put back into the text. The backslash that was before it will be removed in (1), and then put back in (7). This will not really do anything, just make the regex not destroy already escaped characters.

In the case of (2) matching, it will either be an end of line backslash that is consumed (6) and put back (7), or it will be a `$` or `@` which is consumed (4) and put back (7), with a backslash in front.

So basically what the OP says in the comment is happening.

Comment: THANKS so much！Additionally，can ```($2 || $1)``` be changed into```($1 || $2)```? Because i tested that position change of $1 and $2 will not change the result.

Comment: `($1 || $2)` is logically very different than `($2 || $1)`, though they may have produced the same results for your data set. The expression is saying "use $x if it's true(*), or use $y". Think of it this way: if both are true, which one do you prefer to use? [* = Perl's idea of "false" is: undefined, 0, "0", (), or an empty string ("") -- anything else is true. See https://perlmaven.com/boolean-values-in-perl]

Comment: @joseph No those expressions are not interchangeable. There are ways to improve the regex, but I think that is a new question.